# D3 Outer padding - padd the left bar only

Tags: d3.js, scale

I have a two column vertical bar chart.

I dont want the left hand bar to be flush with the Y axis.

So I used PaddingOuter() to specify an inset as follows:

```
var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).paddingInner(0.1).paddingOuter(0.5).align(0.1);
```

I works nicely.

Except that the right hand bar (its a two column chart) is also inset.

I only want the left hand bar inset.

Is there a solution to this..?

Answer (score -1):

Start the range at the amount you want to offset by, e.g., `rangeRound([10, width])`